# Why does gradient load incorrectly in Chrome?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gradient

I am HTML5 beginner and I just have created  [my portfolio page](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1301955/portfolio/index.html) using Twitter Bootstrap. I generated my gradient by using [colorzilla gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

Unfortunately sometimes my gradient loads incorrectly in Chrome and it looks like this:

[image: incorrect gradient]

What's wrong with my page?

Comment: I assume the stylesheet you added the gradients in is separate from bootstrap? If so, add your custom stylesheet below the bootstrap stylesheet...(so that it loads after the bootstrap one) - Let me know of that works

Comment: you can even try to remove the bootstrap.css and see how your gradient renders then... It is possible that your css is clashing with bootstrap's

Comment: @DextrousDave - I don't think it is the problem since it renders the gradient only it looks weird , I have the same problem with chrome, once i open the console and close it, everything looks fine

Comment: Your question is currently a guessing game for us. Can you please track down the offending code and post the relevant bits (to reproduce this issue) in your question? Currently, (a) we have to go through your entire site and (b) if you fix your linked site this question won't be useful to future visitors anymore.

Comment: yeah thats weird...Initial load in chrome show the odd gradient. I opened element inspector/console and it went away...
Try generating a different gradient with different effects/settings and see what happens

Comment: It is one of those infamous Chrome rendering bugs. Just resize your browser one px to trigger a repaint and everything will look fine. Unfortunately there is nothing you can do besides waiting for the next Chrome update, unless you want to apply really ugly hacks for something that will be fixed in a week max.

Comment: @Jeroen When I am simplifying my page, problem doesnt't occur, so I can't attach short sample code for future visitors. Visitor, if You have a problem with gradient in Chrome browser, try change colors in gradient to HEX values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the Bootstap gradient mixin gives, you could see if the results are any different:

```
.iamcoming {
background-color: #525252;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #666666);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#444444), to(#666666));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #666666);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #666666);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #444444, #666666);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff444444', endColorstr='#ff666666', GradientType=0);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank You, Your answer is solution. HEX values seems to work good.

Comment: That's great, I'm pleased this helped ... must admit though that when I first posted this I was thinking it could be an issue related to the vendor specific code, not HEX vs RGB ;) On further searching I've seen some other reports that HEX is the most reliable, not sure if this is correct or just good luck in this case.  Good luck with your apps.